# Read umask for a user

Tags: osx, posix, umask

Plenty of examples on how to **set** `umask` for a user... but how do you read (or uncover) the default `umask` for a given user (say the logged in user)

Comment: Note that `umask` is not associated with a _user_ but with a process.

Comment: ic. so what I *think* I want, ideally, is for the `umask` to change to `002` whenever I run a particular command (`$ brew …`) but it can default back to `022` at all other times. **possible or wishful thinking?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the `umask` command...

```
dennis@lightning:~$ umask
0002
```

Comment: LOL- well, that was easy (read: obvious)! thx

Answer (score 1):

To make sure a command is called with a specific command, you could wrap it inside a script or a function that starts a subshell with the `umask` updated. You could put that function definition in your shell configuration file like `.bashrc` for `bash` or `.zshrc` for `zsh`.

Something like:

```
brew() (
  umask 002 &&
    command brew "$@"
)
```